# How to get boolean value with requst getAttribute java?

Tags: java, httprequest, getattribute

How to get boolean value set as an attribute value in request.

Consider the following snippet

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException  {

 boolean isOriginal = (boolean) req.getAttribute(“isOriginalFile");
//Some code
}
```

Where the request may/may not contain the `isOriginalFile` attribute. How to handle this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that getting `false` when attribute is `null` is what you expect:

```
boolean isOriginal = Boolean.TRUE == req.getAttribute("isOriginalFile");
```

Then if you set the attribute to anything else than `Boolean.TRUE` (including `null`) you will get `false`.

You may set it in either way:

```
req.setAttribute("isOriginalFile", Boolean.TRUE);
req.setAttribute("isOriginalFile", (Boolean) true);
req.setAttribute("isOriginalFile", true);
```

But not as String (because it will be then evaluated to `false`):

```
req.setAttribute("isOriginalFile", "true");
```

Comment: Nice one ! Working fine :-)

Answer (score 1):

Parse the value returned by the getAttribute method.

```
boolean isOriginal = Boolean.valueOf(String.valueOf(req.getAttribute("isOriginalFile")));
```

The getAttribute returns an Object, and the Boolean.valueOf method takes a String parameter. So, first convert the returned value to String and then parse it.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)

Comment: Should be `Boolean.valueOf(...)`, and that opening quote needs fixing

Comment: Corrected it. Thanks!

Comment: Note that if there is no such attribute, String.valueOf() will throw an NPE

Comment: @BalajiKrishnan, `String.valueOf(Object)` does not throw NPE. Since the return type of `req.getAttribute` is Object, it will specifically match the overload `String.valueOf(Object)` and so it works!